# SmbFileOutputStream write creating corrupted jpg files

Tags: java, upload, corrupt, jcifs

I'm using JCIFS SmbFileOutputStream write to upload jpg (and mp4) files to a share on a local Windows network. While this works well most of the time, I sometimes find that the resulting files are corrupt - e.g. if it's a jpg perhaps only the top part of the photo will be legible/visible.

I have the upload in a try/catch block, but it is not throwing an exception. Is there any way that I can verify that a file has been uploaded correctly?

```
try {
    if (debugging_on) {
        logger.info("UploadService.011 UploadFiles: uploading file:" + destFileName);
    }
    SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sFile);
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
            sSourceFilePath));
    byte[] buf = new byte[16 * 1024 * 1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = fileInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
        sfos.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    fileInputStream.close();
    sfos.close();
    // Update the database to include the date/time of this upload
    millisStart = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    sql = "UPDATE upload_history SET file_uploaded_date = "
            + millisStart + " WHERE filename = '" + filename + "'";
    db.execSQL(sql);

} catch (Exception e) {
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText("Upload error - check folder permissions");
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mNotifyBuilder.build());
    return "WriteFailure";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sfos.close();
```

needs to go before

```
fileInputStream.close();
```

Close the output before you close the input, 
Adding 'sfos.flush()' couldn't hurt.